# Has anyone worked with NFC with Java, javax.microedition.contactless?

Tags: java, android, api, nfc

I have been trying to look into this and it seems hard to find good solid info. Is there anyone out there that has created any java packages that interact with NFC phones, cards, etc. I haven't been able to find a lot on how NFC works really. I just want to be able to read the id of the phone, or its phone number, when it scans. Any way to do this?

I was reading this:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/nfc/

which mentions the package `javax.microedition.contactless`

but can't seem to figure out how to implement it. I am not great at Java, only in my second semester. This over my head?

Comment: Android has it's own NFC library http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html

Comment: Will android only work with that library or is there another library that works more openly? Thanks

Comment: I guess it will only work with that library because Android does not want you to access hardware outside of their permission controlled system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android has own Java API, which differs from JavaMe. This applies not only to NFC, but also to other areas. The above mentioned API you can use on JavaMe NFC enabled phones like Nokia 6212, some Samsungs and Sagem.

If you plan to use NFC I suggest you to either use the Android - there are 2 widely available NFC phones on the market or Symbian, where is dozens of models already released. The other option is go with RIM BlackBerry.

BR
STeN